# AxWindowsMediaPlayer.settings.rate in windows media player has no effect

Tags: vb.net

I am implementing a video player with vb.net 2015 and windows media player, but the setting of rate has no effect on the video player.

I have not tried anything, I'm starting

AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate -= 0.4

Any result

Comment: That's pretty normal, it is not an "easy" property.  At issue is what happens to the audio, slowing it down and still keeping it recognizable is hard to do.  In general it depends on the specific media format and you can only expect to be able to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

- For positive values i tried += 10 and it worked just fine (+10)
- For Negative values you can go down to -= 1, it's the minimum value (-1)

if you put something less than -1 it will say value does not fall in the range..

As in your case please put the line on form load event so it works

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate -= 0.8
End Sub
```

I just tried it on an mp3 file and an mp4 video file and it worked well for me

Comment: No, it also has no effect, maybe you should apply a mathematical formula due to the compression of the mp4 h264 video?

Comment: I mentioned that i tried it on MP4 video and the video was running like slow motion so the problem is something else on your side..

Comment: `but the setting of rate has no effect on the video player` you still want me to send a video for proof? :P